# How to select and rename the sub column and remove the main column from the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with pandas dataframe. I have written a code using custom aggregation.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data = {'item': ['d1','d1','d1','d1','d1','d1','d1','d1','d1','d1'], 'price': [65,52,93,74,46,67,62,50,49,41]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def pass_percent(series):
    obtained_total=0
    grand_marks=0
    for mark in series:
        if mark>=35:
            obtained_total = obtained_total + mark
            grand_marks = grand_marks + 1
    return (obtained_total/(grand_marks*100))*100


df1 = df.groupby('dept').agg({'marks': ['sum', pass_percent]})

print(df1)
```

The output is like

```
           marks
       sum     pass_percent
dept
d1     599         59.9
```

What I what is to have a dataframe like this. What to do this?

```
       total     final_pass_percent
dept
d1     599         59.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use named tuples in `agg()` method:

```
df1=df.groupby('item').agg(total=('price','sum'),final_pass_percent=('price',pass_percent))
```

OR in 2 steps after aggregration change the column names:

```
df1=df.groupby('item').agg({'price': ['sum', pass_percent]})
df1.columns=['total','final_pass_percent']
```

output of `df1`:

```
        total   final_pass_percent
item        
d1      599     59.9
```

Comment: @Arud then sir you can try consider accepting this as an answer to indicate others that the issue is solved......Thanks **:)**